# How to declare success/fail return types in typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript-generics

I have a package that simply does an HTTP call and returns either a success response or an error response. I am trying to make it so that you get IntelliSense on both success and error.

This is what I have:

```
class ResultSuccess {
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
}

class ResultError {
  error: boolean;
}

export function magic(): Promise<ResultSuccess> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => resolve(plainToClass(ResultSuccess, json as ResultSuccess)))
        .catch(err => {
            reject(plainToClass(ResultError, { error: true } as ResultError));
        });
});
```

}

This works, and I get intelisense on the outcome but if i motify the retun to somethign like:

```
function magic(): Promise<ResultSuccess | ResultError>
```

I no longer get intelisense on the success or fail outcomes.

I'm new to typescript, can someone suggest a way to hanlde this or can someone see an issue?

Comment: `I no longer get intelisense on the success or fail outcomes.` How so? Btw rejection cannot be typed: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7588#issuecomment-199079907

Comment: I get the hint that the function will return ResultSuccess | ResultError but I do not get the autocomplete of the property names(outcome.userIs or outcome.error).

Is this a correct way to handle https calls then? (type the successful outcome and in case it's not successful let them figure out the error?).

Answer (score 2):

## Solution #1: errors are thrown

> I'm new to typescript

In this case I allow myself to rewrite your `magic` function using `async` and `await`, because it is the way to work in 2019:

```
export async function magic(): Promise<ResultSuccess> {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
    const json = await response.json();
    return plainToClass(ResultSuccess, json as ResultSuccess);
  } catch (err) {
    throw plainToClass(ResultError, { error: true });
  }
}
```

The return value is a promise of `ResultSuccess`. The function never returns a `ResultError`, but it can throw it. An example on how to use it:

```
async function useMagic() {
  try {
    const result = await magic();
    // 'result' is of type 'ResultSuccess'
  } catch (err) {
    // 'err' is of type 'any' and you know it is a 'ResultError'
  }
}
```

## Solution #2: errors are not thrown but returned

If you decide that errors must be returned as result values, you can do that:

```
export async function magic2(): Promise<ResultSuccess | ResultError> {
  try {
    // … same code as previously …
  } catch (err) {
    return plainToClass(ResultError, { error: true });
  }
}
```

Then, when you use the result value, you have to determine if this is an error or a success. Here is a solution:

Write a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```
function isResultError(result: ResultSuccess | ResultError): result is ResultError {
  return result["error"] !== undefined;
}
```

Then, use it:

```
async function useMagic2() {
  const result = await magic2();
  if (isResultError(result)) {
    // Here, 'result' is of type 'ResultError'
  } else {
    // Here, 'result' is of type 'ResultSuccess'
  }
}
```

Comment: Solution 1 makes sense, thanks for all the details. 

Would it be a good practice to return the error class and check in the catch if the error is an instance of the ResultError?

er => er instanceof myPackage.ResultError ?  console.log("yap") : console.log("nope")

Comment: @johnnyshrewd With the code above, it is unnecessary to check the type of the error because the whole code of `magic` is surrounded by a `try` / `catch`. It cannot throw something else. You can just cast if you want autocompletion: `(err as ResultError).error`.

Comment: What are the pros and cons of solution #1 vs #2? It seems like I am reading more and more TS code using solution #2, at least at a low level. I'm trying to decide which approach I should focus on, and why. Thanks.